# Why can I only serialize a Type[] if it is wrapped in an object?

Tags: protobuf-net

I am struggling more than I expected with protobuf-net. It is beautiful and fast and easy on the simple case, but I admit I'm having trouble off the beaten path. I am trying to serialize and deserialize some objects in runtime as opposed to using attributes, but I've found a variety of issues. The first is this; In runtime I can Serialize an array of integers, but not Types, unless I wrap them first. Below is what I mean:

```cs
// Fails with 
// System.InvalidOperationException
// Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.RuntimeType
//   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowUnexpectedType(Type type) in C:\Code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 1471
//   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TrySerializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoWriter writer, Type type, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Object value, Boolean isInsideList, Object parentList) in C:\Code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 172
//   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value) in C:\Code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 194
//   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context) in C:\Code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 222
//   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance) in C:\Code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 93
//   at my bit of code

public static void SerializeMyClass()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, new[] {typeof(int)});
    }
}
```

```cs
// Works perfectly (and deserializes correctly too, not shown here for brevity)

[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public Type[] Types;
}

public static void SerializeMyClass()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, new MyClass {Types = new[] {typeof(int)}});
    }
}
```

What am I not understanding? Is it possible to serialize an array of Types without wrapping them first, and if so, what must I do differently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version here would be: because `Type` has special handling, and it has never been tested and fixed in this scenario. I agree that it is an odd and unexpected behavior, though, and I have fixed it in the v3 codebase [in this commit](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/f887ff59f72de091efff4d0bf71a1ab56b37b3c6). This fix will not be back ported to v2 though.

Note that at the payload level, there is no fundamental difference between the wrapped and non-wrapped version, so without the v3 fix, the other workaround here is: use your `MyClass` exactly like you are in the code in the question.

However! I would caution you against serializing `Type` too eagerly; as you can see in the payloads in the tests, `Type` has an unfortunate feature in that because it encodes assembly metadata, it can get awkward if the assemblies change. And between .NET framework and .NET core, the *assemblies do change*. You can hack around this by subscribing to the `DynamicTypeFormatting` event on a type model, but ... this is just making more and more work.